# How to postfix with a string each line of a multiline selection?

Tags: rectangle

Reminder:`C-x r t string <RET>` replaces rectangle contents with string on each line (string-rectangle). https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html

Can I use this, or an analogue command, starting from:

```
{Curiosity
{Killed
{The Cat
```

to get:

```
{Curiosity}
{Killed}
{The Cat}
```

?

Comment: I don't use rectangles, but the `multiple-cursors` library by Magnar Sveen can handle this in a split-second flat.

Comment: Rectangles are irrelevant in your example. Maybe, you need to expand it to get to the point. But in your example you can just call `query-replace-regexp` with `$` as search string and `}` as replacement. The command is normally bound to `C-M-%`